# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource when intellij idea deploy maven spring mvc web project on tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

After a build REST API web project with maven dependency spring MVC and Hibernate, I package the war in command line and upload it to tomcat on ubuntu by tomcat manager html page, it works.But when I try to deploy the war on my local tomcat (Windows platform), I get error from tomcat catalina log:

```
七月 19, 2016 8:37:15 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
严重: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vstar]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1836)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    ... 54 more

七月 19, 2016 8:37:15 下午 org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
严重: Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vstar]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1836)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

七月 19, 2016 8:37:15 下午 org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
严重: Exception invoking method createStandardContext
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:309)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vstar]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1836)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    ... 31 more
```

here is my parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.lebooks.vstar</groupId>
    <artifactId>vstar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>vstar-api</module>
        <module>vstar-order</module>
        <module>vstar-base</module>
        <module>vstar-customer</module>
        <module>vstar-authorization</module>
        <module>vstar-work</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.springframework>4.1.6.RELEASE</version.springframework>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springframework}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springframework}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springframework}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

this is my rest api module pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>vstar</artifactId>
        <groupId>me.lebooks.vstar</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>vstar-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>vstar-api</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.lebooks.vstar</groupId>
            <artifactId>vstar-order</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>junit</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>junit</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>3.8.1</version>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>vstar-api</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

there is almost nothing in the API module.

I am not familiar to maven.

Comment: do you have `spring-core` jar file in classpath?

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource` means you have missing jar

add this in `pom.xml`

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
 In consideration of Transitive dependencies ，I have add spring-webmvc dependency to my parent pom.xml, Does that means I have the spring-core dependency already?

I have check my .im file(intellij idea), there is such node `<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE" level="project" />
    ` in it, and I can import org.springframework.core.io.Resource in my code, Does that means spring-core is in my classpath already?

Comment: `spring core` and `spring mvc` are different , now did you try to add `spring-core`?

Comment: Why are you adding version 3.1.1 if this one seems to be outdated? Or am I wrong somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on your web project in Project Explorer -> select 'Properties'. Under project properties, select 'Deployment Assembly'.

You can try to remove Maven Dependencies, apply, compile your code and then add  Maven Dependencies again. This time the project will start again on tomcat.

Sometimes tomcat on eclipse just stops deploying your project libs when using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

## Dependency scope: compile

I had the dependency in the pom before the problem, but with the wrong scope (`test` instead of `compile`).

Wrong dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Right dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```